# Unable to make API call to a service in react native

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, fetch

I'm running a NodeJS service in my local machine which has some APIs in it that I created. I'm trying to hit those APIs using my react native application but I'm getting the following error:

```
error [TypeError: Network request failed]
```

I'm using fetch to make call to my service:

```
const newUser = fetch('http://localhost:5001/{firebase_service}/us-central1/app/user', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: userPayload
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Can anyone help me get unblocked ?

Comment: The problem is in the localhost because localhost refers to your emulator. change localhost to 10.0.2.2 so your URL should be http://10.0.2.2:5001/{firebase_service}/us-central1/app/user

Comment: Thank you @Majidlotfinia for your help. I updated my url and it worked. Is there any particular reason why we used 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost ? localhost was working fine when I was trying to hit the above endpoint via postman.

Comment: Great. I posted my comment as an answer. please accept that as an answer. After that, I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the localhost because localhost refers to your emulator. change localhost to 10.0.2.2 so your URL should be 10.0.2.2:5001{firebase_service}/us-central1/app/user

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to connect to your local server from your app. but as [Majid lotfinia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4592051/majid-lotfinia) pointed out, it is possible that localhost:5001 is pointing to the emulator (or your phone if you're using your physical device) rather than your desktop. Also in many cases react native does not work with http websites, and https is mandatory. So i'd suggest you use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for testing , until you have moved your server to a cloud.

Comment: Hello,
I tried what @Majid had suggested and it worked for me and hence, didn't try the above approach. Thanks for your help tho. :')